# Different version of Python cannot find modules

Tags: opensuse, python, libraries

In my Suse system I have these 2 versions of Python:

```
# which python2.6
# /usr/bin/python2.6

# which python2.4
# /usr/local/bin/python2.4
```

2.6 is the system one, and 2.4 was compiled by me.

If I try to import a package using the 2.4 version:

```
# python2.4 -c "import bz2; print bz2.__doc__"
```

I get the following error:

```
# ImportError: No module named bz2
```

What is the correct way to proceed with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I have no problems with system Python2.6, so the modules are installed. But I don't know how to handle it for Python2.4

Comment: please refer to supported versions, some of module are supported from x and higher milestone of python.

Comment: If it is a manually compiled python installation, then you need to install the bzip2 and bzip2-devel packages and then recompile and reinstall python.

Comment: I might be wrong, but don't you need to set PYTHONPATH correctly so that Python 2.4 looks in the right place?

Comment: @peterph I think the default behavior is to look into the Python installation lib path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that there is a bz2module.c that comes with the Python 2.4 source, but does not appear to be compiled by default and there is nothing in Modules/Setup for it.  Likely because the development package for bz2 is not installed by default.  Try to find the bzlib.h file on your system:

```
$ find /usr/include -name bzlib.h
```

If that does not exist, then install the appropriate library package (libbz2-dev on Debian/Ubuntu).

After that try adding the following to Modules/Setup.local and then recompiling python 2.4.

```
bz2 bz2module.c
```

Comment: Tried that, but got errors during `make` :`libpython2.4.a(bz2module.o): In function 'BZ2Decomp_decompress':
/home/incoming/Python-2.4.2/./Modules/bz2module.c:1841: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzDecompress'`  any idea?

Comment: It isn't failing on my side, so I'm not sure where the problem could be.  Since the build is finding bzlib.h, the most likely reason is that there is a version mismatch between what you installed for the bzip2 development package and what is expected in Python.  The version of libbz2-dev on my system is 1.0.6-1, what was installed on your system?

Comment: Just took an alternative path. But you're probably correct, will mark your answer.